# How to stop 302 redirect after submitting form to form handler? [Pardot]

Tags: javascript, salesforce, http-status-code-302, pardot

Currently I have a form that I am using to post to a pardot form handler. When you successfully post to a form handler in pardot it responds by sending you a 302 redirect. I don't want to redirect to another page. I want to stay on the current page and use the response to show a success or error message. I have tried a multitude of things using javascript:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    });
```

This just doesn't submit the form at all.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    return false;
    });
```

This doesn't submit the form as well.

I also cannot use AJAX as Pardot returns a cors error when you try to use AJAX to post to this. Anyone have any idea on how to handle this?

Ideally I would love to use the 302 redirect to construct my response on the page.